# What's the scope of local vars in javascript for statement headers?

Tags: javascript

```
function test()
{
    i = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++);
    alert(i);
}
```

I've tested this in Firefox. Does it give the same result in all browsers? Is the i in the for statement header local to the for statement or to the function?

Comment: what are you trying to doing?

Comment: hoisting, learn about it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: To the function. Read a tutorial.

Comment: `var` are function scoped, you will want to use `let` for `for` scope.

Comment: @Keith Is var function scoped even when inside a block under the for statement? But let makes it for scoped, even as the code stands?

Comment: a `var` is function scoped no matter what you do with it.

Comment: @Henrik3 `let` and `const` are `block` scoped, meaning within any { }

Comment: @snapjs  If there wasn't another `var` later it would be global.  But the `var` that's there get's hoisted.

Comment: @Henrik3 please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable

Comment: To make this easier to understand, the code is really `var i = 10; for (i = 0; i < 1; i ++)`  so basically the `i=10` just becomes a no op..

Comment: @snapjs Aha, so var is not like declaring local vars in C but let is?

Comment: @Keith What does hoisted mean? I don't understand "becomes a no op".

Comment: @Henrik3 can you see my code above, basically the `var` gets pushed to the top of the function.  It's the reason `let` & `const` are here.. I can't think of any reason to use `var` anymore, `let` & `const` are the way to go.  Before `let` / `const`, we had to create what are called closures.. eg.. `(function () { for(var i = 0; i < 1; i ++) {} }())` , here the `var` is local to the for loop, because it's local to the function closure.

Comment: @Keith Now I understand. It's quite simple, actually. In js there are only 2 kinds of vars: global and function local. That is, until let vars came along. Yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` is `function` scoped, therefore your `function`

```
function test()
{
    i = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++);
    alert(i);
}
```

will declare an `i` variable, override it with another one with similar name in a `for`, resulting in 1 and this value will be alerted.